# How to check no match and match between two data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I compare both below sets in Excel. If **Item#** of Set A and Set B match then check for Date,Amount,% between the two sets. If they do not match then display "no match" else display actual(see below result). The data are unsorted.

```
       Set A                                       Set B


Item#  Date     Amount  %                  Item#   Date      Amount  %
4     1/3/21    $22    20%                  5     1/23/21    $220   40%
3     1/2/21    $22    20%                  4     1/2/21     $22    20%
5     1/23/21   $220   40%                  3     1/2/21     $33    20%
```

Result

```
Item#  Date     Amount  %                  
4    No Match    $22    20%
3    1/2/21    No Match 20%
5    1/23/21    $220    40%
```

Comment: If you want to do this in Excel, why do you have the `google-sheets` tag?

Comment: Have you considered the match() function? Or if()?

Comment: No, have not try on match. How does it work on with "no match"?

Comment: Then wrap in iferror().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=CHOOSE((INDEX(F1:I4,MATCH(A9:A11,F1:F4,0),MATCH(B8:D8,F1:I1,0))=B2:D4)+1,"No Match",B2:D4)`

In the above set A being range `A1:D4` and set B range `F1:I4`
The result set is in range `A8:D11`

The formula first evaluates if the lookup value of set B equals A, being TRUE or FALSE. Then adding 1 converts TRUE and FALSE to 1 and 0 and adds 1.
So if it doesn't match it chooses 0+1= 1. If it matches it chooses 1+1= 2.

[image]

Comment: P.b - Yes, it works! Thanks so much for the explanation. Appreciate your help.